# Get Team's Planner using App Only permission in Azure Function

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

Is there any example how I can achieve following requirement:

I need to read Planner Plans from Group in an Azure Function trough Graph Api.

Application permissions are not supported, only delegated.

I tried with ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder with OnBehalfOfProvider, but no luck. I do not know how to set UserAssertion in this case.

Also, username and password flow is not an option, because end user can use MFA.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Microsoft Planner APIs on Microsoft Graph do not support Application permissions (App-only) . This is confirmed in the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Please vote up the feature request for this https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/5904632-application-permissions-to-task-api

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for your answer. I was expecting something like this. Is there some workaround?

Comment: @mgordic - Please upvote the feature as suggested by Jeremy, so that feature can be considered to be implemented by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Planner APIs now support Application Only permissions!

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/new-microsoft-planner-api-capabilities-now-available-in-microsoft-graph/